# How to record screen when using eglfs on Broadcom VideoCore IV

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, broadcom, drm, screencasting

I have a full-screen Qt app running on a Raspberry Pi 3 using the "eglfs" platform. It draws using KMS/DRM and the `/dev/dri/core0` GPU device. The GPU is a Broadcom VideoCore IV.

I'd like to record the screen and have not been successful. The closest I've got is:

1. Using `ffmpeg` and the `kmsgrab` input device. Unfortunately `ffmpeg -f kmsgrab -i - -vf 'hwdownload,format=bgr0' output.mp4` produces garbled video, as shown below.

   [image: Garbled output from ffmpeg]
2. Redirect Qt to the framebuffer. For example: `./my_app -platform linuxfb:fb=/dev/fb0`. Then the more straight-forward `ffmpeg -f fbdev -i /dev/fb0 output.mp4` works. Unfortunately `linuxfb` does not render features from `Qt5Compat.GraphicalEffects` such as `layer.effect`, so my buttons do not show.

Given the garbled output from `ffmpeg` seems so close, I've tried passing various `format_modifier`'s from [drm_fourcc.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/uapi/drm/drm_fourcc.h#L380) but have not seen any difference. Surely there's a set of `hwmap` or `format_modifier` flags that will ensure the output resembles what appears on screen?

For reference I'm using kernel version 5.4.83-v8 and `dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d`. I could adjust those things if I thought it would make any difference.

Comment: `jkqxz` in #ffmpeg on IRC kindly identified the distortion as likely to be the Broadcom VC4 "T" format tiling, `DRM_FORMAT_MOD_BROADCOM_VC4_T_TILED`. Alas, we still don't have a way to decode it. The `hwdownload` filter can only deal with linear (as documented), the `untile` video filter does not help, and attempts to use the `vulkan` device for `hwmap` result in "Failed to created derived device context: -12. ... Cannot allocate memory".

Comment: You can change the pixel format of eglfs in a config. See https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/5.15.2/src/plugins/platforms/eglfs/deviceintegration/eglfs_kms/qeglfskmsgbmscreen.cpp#L158-L160

There doesn't seem to be a way to explicitly disable modifiers, but maybe a different pixel format doesn't support tiling, so it gets disabled.

It could also be that eglfs_kms isn't being used.

Comment: @any1 I tried creating some simple `config.json` (`{"device": "/dev/dri/card0","outputs": [{"name": "DSI","format": "xrgb2101010"}]}`) and launching the app with `QT_QPA_EGLFS_KMS_CONFIG=config.json`. I couldn't detect any difference.